# how to configure a user's home to reside in a loop device?

Tags: home-directory, loop-device

I'm trying to configure our guest account to reside in a loop device mounted to /home/gast.

On startup the loop device gets created via this line in **/etc/fstab**:

*tmpfs /home/gast tmpfs size=3g user*

in **/etc/profile** I entered the procedure to copy the content of a preconfigured user into the mounted loop device via:

*chown gast:gast /home/gast && cp -r /home/gast-default/* /home/gast && chown -R gast:gast /home/gast*

On reboot it turns out, that /etc/profile doesn't seem to have root privileges any more. I get error messages complaining about missig permissions and in the end a virgin home directory for the guest user. This isn't helping because my guests have almost no experience on PCs yet alone Linux. The structure in /home/gast-default/ copes with that

Question: How and where do I enter the copy procedure earlier than /etc/profile? Before Systemd it used to be /etc/rc.local, but apparently this isn't supported any more.

Thanks
Waldgeist

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/profile` is a file that is sourced when you log in. That is why the changing of user and copying does not proceed. `/etc/profile` is sourced for each user, whereas `~/.profile` is user specific.

The "modern" way is to create a systemd service that does that.

More easy will be to create a crontab entry for the root user, that does the copying @reboot.